# Yii Framework Unable to Print Error Message after login attempt failure

Tags: yii

Hi i am unable to print error message in yii after login attempt failure , Below is the code of my controller , view , loginform (model) and UserIdentity class invloved in login .
First here is code of controller

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $model = new LoginForm();
    // if it is ajax validation request
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    // collect user input data
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if ($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
}
```

after controller i have following code in my view file

```
<?php
            $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'login-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'enableClientValidation' => true,
                'clientOptions' => array(
                    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'id' => 'form-contact'
                ),
            ));
            echo CHtml::errorSummary($model);
            ?>
            <div id="form-left">
                <label for="text-email">Email(<span style="color: red;">*</span>)</label><br />
                <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'email', array('class' => 'input')); ?><br />
                <label for="text-password">Password (<span style="color: red;">*</span>)</label><br />
                <?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password', array('class' => 'input')); ?><br />
                <br>
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login', array('class' => 'button', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:50px;')); ?>
            </div>
            <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Here is code of Login Form Model

```
<?php

/**
 * LoginForm.php
 *
 * @author: antonio ramirez <antonio@clevertech.biz>
 * Date: 7/22/12
 * Time: 8:37 PM
 */
class LoginForm extends CFormModel {

    public $email;
    public $password;
    private $_identity;
    private $_user = null;

    /**
     * Model rules
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('password, email', 'required'),
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns attribute labels
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'email' => Yii::t('labels', 'E-mail'),
            'password' => Yii::t('labels', 'Password'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates user input against DB
     * @param $attribute
     * @param $params
     */
    public function authenticate($attribute, $params) {
        $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->email, $this->password);
        if (!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect email or password.');
    }

    /**
     * Login
     * @return bool
     */
    public function login() {

        if ($this->_identity === null) {
            $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->email, $this->password);
            $this->_identity->authenticate();
        }
        if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns
     * @return null
     */
    public function getUser() {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $attribute = strpos($this->email, '@') ? 'email' : 'email';
            $this->_user = User::model()->find(array('condition' => $attribute . '=:loginname', 'params' => array(':loginname' => $this->email)));
        }
        return $this->_user;
    }

}
```

here is my user identity

```
<?php

class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {

    private $_id;

    public function authenticate() {
        $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email' => $this->username));
        if ($user === null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else if ($user->password !== md5($this->password)) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        } else {
            $this->_id = $user->id;
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return $this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens now when login failed?

Comment: redirect to login page with no error message

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. You need to change the `LoginForm`-Model. I inserted comments where i changed something.

First change the method `authenticate` to:

```
public function authenticate($attribute, $params) {
    $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->email, $this->password);

    // Change from "if (!$this->_identity->authenticate())" to:
    if ($this->_identity->authenticate() !== UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
        $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect email or password.');
}
```

And then the method `login` because there's no result when calling login() and there's a authentication problem:

```
public function login() {

        if ($this->_identity === null) {
            $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->email, $this->password);
            $this->_identity->authenticate();
        }
        if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
            return true;
        }
        return false; // add this line for the case when authentication failed
}
```